# PHP My Page is not Displaying anything After I Use isset()

Tags: php, forms, class

I have an index.php which basically displays an HTML content. All was working fine until I put a form and an if statement to check if the submit button is pressed.

Now the page is totally blank. Checking the source code in the browser, even the HTML tags are not present. If I remove the is set part I get an undefined index fname... error.

```
    <?php require_once 'config/autoload.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $fname = clean_data($_POST['fname']);
        $lname = clean_data($_POST['lname']);
        $your_question = clean_data($_POST['question']);

        try {
            $homepage = new Page;
            $author = new Author($fname, $lname);
            $question = new Question($your_question, $author);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage(), '<br>';
            exit;
        }

        $homepage->content = <<<_END
        <p>Hello {$author->getFirstName()} {$author->getLastName()}!</p><br>

        <p>You ask: {$question->getQuestion()}</p>

        <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="post" role="form">
        <label for="fname">Enter your first name</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="30"><br>
        <label for="lname">Enter your last name</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="30"><br>
        <label for="question">What is your question?</label><br>
        <textarea id="question" name="question" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        _END;
        $homepage->display();
    }

    function clean_data($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = strip_tags($data);
        $data = addslashes($data);
        return $data;
    }
```

I followed one of the suggestions. I put the if isset before the try catch. But I get these errors:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $fname = clean_data($_POST['fname']);
        $lname = clean_data($_POST['lname']);
        $your_question = clean_data($_POST['question']);
    }
    try {...
    ?>
```

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: fname on line 11
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: lname on line 11
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: your_question on line 12.

But at least now the page is displaying.

Comment: could you please do a var_dump($_POST) before the if statement and see what is the value of $_POST['submit'] in the case where nothing is displayed

Comment: maybe move the if's `}` to after the try block?

Comment: var_dump($_POST); array (size=0)
  empty - But why is even the html code not showing like <html><head>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, you'll want to move the form outside of your if clause, cause right now you are asking if the form is submitted then do something, but since the form you are checking is inside of your IF clause, it will never be displayed. so do something like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 <php code>
}
 <INSERT FORM HERE>
```

**UPDATE 2**

The general issue is that the code is trying to access variables that haven't been set, seeing as it looks like you are both trying to display the users question and allow him to ask a question at the same time I'd properly do something like this.

```
$fname = isset($_POST['fname']) ? clean_data($_POST['fname']) : NULL;
$lname = isset($_POST['lname']) ? clean_data($_POST['lname']) : NULL;
$your_question = isset($_POST['question']) ? clean_data($_POST['question']) : NULL;


try {
   $homepage = new Page;
   $author = new Author($fname, $lname);
   $question = new Question($your_question, $author);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage(), '<br>';
   exit;
}
$homepage->content = <<<_END
<p>Hello {$author->getFirstName()} {$author->getLastName()}!</p><br>

<p>You ask: {$question->getQuestion()}</p>
<form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="post" role="form">
<label for="fname">Enter your first name</label><br>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="30"><br>
<label for="lname">Enter your last name</label><br>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="30"><br>
<label for="question">What is your question?</label><br>
<text area id="question" name="question" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
 _END;
$homepage->display();
```

Comment: Maybe what complicates this is that all the content including the form is assigned to a class property. Should I just rewrite my code? Because all output is handled by that $homepage->display() and it includes the $content.

Comment: @Joey It really depends what you are trying to achieve. But as for what I can see from the code you have provided, the $homepage->display will not be called, because the $_POST['submit'] isn't set, and php won't enter the if clause where your form and $homepage is set.

Comment: @Joey - A way you can test whether this is the issue is that you change the isset($_POST['submit']) to isset($_GET['submit']) and then when you call your page you add ?submit=Submit to the end of your url, (example: localhost/index.php?submit=Submit.. If the form then displays you'll have to move the form out and $homepage->display out of the if clause

Comment: You explained it well to me. Now I get it.

Comment: @Joey Happy to help, hope you've seen my updated explanation :)

Comment: Tried your update. Now I get this error just below the if (): ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: author on line 20, ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function getFirstName() on line 20 as well. The try block is for checking if the required classes are loaded.

Comment: @Joey Updated my answer once more, this should avoid all of your issues

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks for staying with me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $fname = clean_data($_POST['fname']);
    $lname = clean_data($_POST['lname']);
    $your_question = clean_data($_POST['question']);
}
    try {
        $homepage = new Page;
        $author = new Author($fname, $lname);
        $question = new Question($your_question, $author);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(), '<br>';
        exit;
    }

    $homepage->content = <<<_END
    <p>Hello {$author->getFirstName()} {$author->getLastName()}!</p><br>

    <p>You ask: {$question->getQuestion()}</p>

    <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="post" role="form">
    <label for="fname">Enter your first name</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="30"><br>
    <label for="lname">Enter your last name</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="30"><br>
    <label for="question">What is your question?</label><br>
    <text area id="question" name="question" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    _END;
    $homepage->display();

function clean_data($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = addslashes($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your HEREDOC closing part in the very beginning of the line as the documentation mentions: [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
    $homepage->content = <<<_END
    ...
    </form>
_END;
```

Comment: Is _END not at the beginning?

Comment: In the question it's indented. It can not have any white space before the closing tag.